# Why animations and addClass behave different?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a **div** which its **initial** color is **green**.

I don't understand why he is getting the **red** color ** immediately** ,

*while the animations are fine in queue.*

`The queue is fine and by order` , **but** the **color** is changed **immediatly**.

Isn't he supposed to be **after the second animation** ?

**Is there difference between priority of animations vs addClass ?**

```
$("div").show("slow").animate({left:'+=200'},2000).animate({top:'+=200'},2000).css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Note: Your liberal use of text formatting makes the question harder to read. When almost everything is made bold to look important, you have to go through the extra step in your head to ignore all formatting to determine what's *really* important in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `css` method doesn't put the change on the animation queue, so it's changed immediately when you run the code.

You can put the CSS change in the animation queue using the `queue` method:

```
$("div").show("slow")
.animate({left:'+=200'},2000)
.animate({top:'+=200'},2000)
.queue(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

css isn't a queued function. It executes immediately. You can choose between:

```
$("div").show("slow").animate({left:'+=200'},2000)
.animate({top:'+=200'},2000, function(){ $(this).css('background-color','red'); });
```

and

```
$("div").show("slow").animate({left:'+=200'},2000).animate({top:'+=200'},2000)
.queue(function(){ $(this).css('background-color','red'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div")
    .animate({left:'+=200', top:'+=200', display: 'block'}, 2000, 
    function() {
       $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
);
```

Excuse my indenting.